# RMagick - Adjust Brightness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Does anyone know how to adjust the brightness of an image using RMagick?  Rmagick has a number of different functions available, including ones to adjust levels and the hue/brightness/saturation levels, but I need to adjust the old-fashioned brightness/contrast levels.

There are custom functions for me to individually adjust each color channel (RGBA), but I'm not sure how to use levels to adjust the overall brightness.  Messing with the different channels has yielded images that are color-altered.  On GIMP, in the levels menu, the desired functionality I want is under 'Output Levels'. By dragging this below 255, I can achieve a 'darkening' effect.  Is there some kind of equivalent in RMagick to control Output Levels?  I don't see a channel for it.

Examples:

THIS IS ORIGINAL IMAGE:
[image: Original Image]

THIS IS WHAT I WANT:
[image: Desired Result]

THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS WHEN I ADJUST LIGHTNESS (Rmagick's Modulate)
[image: Undesired Result from Lightness]

Comment: Ok--so increasing HSL brightness isn't enough, you want to increase contrast and brightness at the same time, essentially. The RMagick::Image class has a `level` function where you can specify a range, which should be exactly what you need. I'd give you a little example if I was at a computer :) (I'll try later if you don't already get what you need)

Comment: Thank you-- I've been toying around with RMagick's level and level_channel functions, but it keeps turning my white colors into yellow when I adjust the midtones.  I'm really trying to turn it more grey (?), kind of like when you adjust turn down the brightness on a photo in a regular crappy photo editor.

Comment: Hey, you might want to show a 'before' and 'after' of the same image with the sort of transformation you're looking to achieve. (I'm not totally clear what you want.)

Comment: Images added for clarification-- thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you need.

```
img = Magick::Image.read('bT9xc.png')
img.first.level(-Magick::QuantumRange * 0.25, Magick::QuantumRange * 1.25, 1.0).write('out.png')
```

This sets the black point and the white point 'further away' from the range found in the image, which has the effect of making the brightest white in the source image darker, and the darkest black in the source image lighter.

If you want to make it darker overall, just increase the second factor to `Magick::QuantumRange * 1.5` or higher.

Comment: Hey @struthersneil so you have the equivalent for MiniMagick ? what's `Magick::QuantumRange` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `modulate` method: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#modulate

So to increase the brightness by 50% it would be something like:

```
img.modulate(1.5)
```

Comment: Modulate changes the lightness (Hue, Saturation, Lightness), which is different from brightness...  It distorts the colors.

Comment: I was just going off the documentation which I linked, which says "Changes the **brightness**, saturation, and hue." They provide an example as well. Either way, I'm not really sure what you mean by brightness and lightness are different.

Comment: Difference between brightness and lightness added with pictures in the original question. Thanks!